# How to test a function that is used inside another function?

Tags: jestjs

I have a function that receives a color and an array as parameters, if the parameter's color is the same as the constant's color, the function must place the parameter's color inside the array that was passed in the parameter.

```js
const pushCartridgeArray = (color, array) => {
  if (color === BLACK) {
    array.push(Black)
  } else if (color === YELLOW) {
    array.push(Yellow)
  } else if (color === MAGENTA) {
    array.push(Magenta)
  } else if (color === CYAN) {
    array.push(Cyan)
  }
}
```

It is used inside another function of mine:

```js
const filterAlertsBySeverityAndPriority = (
  alerts,
  known_alerts,
  ignorable_alerts
) => {
  let highestPriorityAlert = null
  let highestPriorityError = null
  let cartridges = []

  const alertsArray = Array.isArray(alerts) ? alerts : [alerts]

  if (!alertsArray.length) return null

  alerts &&
    alertsArray.forEach((alertElement) => {
      const alert = {
        StringId: alertElement['psdyn:Alert']?.['locid:StringId'],
        Severity: alertElement['psdyn:Alert']?.['ad:Severity'],
        Priority: alertElement['psdyn:Alert']?.['ad:AlertPriority'],
        Cartridge:
          alertElement['psdyn:Alert']?.['ad:AlertDetails']?.[
            'ad:AlertDetailsMarkerColor'
          ]
      }

      if (
        !alert.StringId ||
        !alert.Severity ||
        !alert.Priority ||
        ignorable_alerts[alert.StringId]
      ) {
        return
      }
      if (
        alert.Severity === 'error' &&
        (highestPriorityError === null ||
          alert.Priority < highestPriorityError.Priority)
      ) {
        highestPriorityError = alert
      }

      if (known_alerts[alert.StringId] && alert.Severity !== 'error') {
        if (
          highestPriorityAlert === null ||
          alert.Priority < highestPriorityAlert.Priority
        ) {
          highestPriorityAlert = alert
          cartridges = []
          pushCartridgeArray(alert.Cartridge, cartridges)
        } else if (alert.Priority === highestPriorityAlert.Priority) {
          pushCartridgeArray(alert.Cartridge, cartridges)
        }
      }
    })
```

In this case, following the conditions of this "mother" function, it is executed and pushes the cartridge parameter.
What I want to know is how can I test this function without exporting it in the file.
The conditions inside it aren't covered by checks.
But I don't know how to access it and test it without exporting it and I can't export it.

Comment: They should be tested separately. I would write a test that mocks the output from your embedded function and then a separate test for your function. Test as a unit.

Comment: My first reaction is to say... that's a big function to unit test, and even more if you want to test the child function. Why can't you export it? Maybe there's an underlying issue to solve before being able to properly unit test things

Comment: It cannot be exported because it is only used within this function, in this case it is an auxiliary function, it is not used in another file so there is no need to export.

Comment: @Toquinhoro That is not a good reason to NOT export a function. A good code should be testable, maintainable, and usable. you might have achieved the "usable" and "maintainable" part, but what you claimed failed at the "testable" part simply because of your unreasonable requirement.

Comment: Counterpoint: it's perfectly reasonable not to expose implementation details of the module, because that leaves you free to refactor them. The child function is already exercised by the tests of the parent function.  You certainly shouldn't (and have to do hacky things to) mock parts of the module you're supposed to be testing. You could make a call on factoring it out of that module for separate testing if getting adequate coverage through the parent is very onerous.

Comment: @Toquinhoro Usually you test private functions by checking the outputs of the public function that calls them, and if it calls other public functions, check what they are called with. But your public parent function doesn't return anything, nor alters input parameter objects. As I can see it, it's impossible to test this code, as it doesn't actually do anything, because everything is garbage-collected when the function ends.